MONGODB: why data structures of min/max in chunks are different?
For a normal user database that is sharded by _id, sh.status() gives you a result like this:
performance63m.users
                        shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                mongodb-shards-3301 1
                                mongodb-shards-9901 1
                                shard-462j3x    2
                                shard-tlvu1m    1
                        { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("668ccef5df83652ac424d9e7") } on : mongodb-shards-9901 Timestamp(2, 0)
                        { "_id" : ObjectId("668ccef5df83652ac424d9e7") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("668ccef5df83652ac427dcea") } on : shard-tlvu1m Timestamp(3, 0)
                        { "_id" : ObjectId("668ccef5df83652ac427dcea") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("668ccef6df83652ac42adfed") } on : mongodb-shards-3301 Timestamp(4, 0)
                        { "_id" : ObjectId("668ccef6df83652ac42adfed") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("668ccef6df83652ac42de2f0") } on : shard-462j3x Timestamp(4, 1)
                        { "_id" : ObjectId("668ccef6df83652ac42de2f0") } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard-462j3x Timestamp(1, 4)


Another example is sharding a collection by a string field, country, in the case here:
flowers.users
                        shard key: { "country" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                shard-462j3x    1
                                shard-tlvu1m    4
                        { "country" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "country" : "France" } on : shard-462j3x Timestamp(2, 0)
                        { "country" : "France" } -->> { "country" : "Germany" } on : shard-tlvu1m Timestamp(2, 1)
                        { "country" : "Germany" } -->> { "country" : "South Korea" } on : shard-tlvu1m Timestamp(1, 2)
                        { "country" : "South Korea" } -->> { "country" : "United States" } on : shard-tlvu1m Timestamp(1, 3)
                        { "country" : "United States" } -->> { "country" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard-tlvu1m Timestamp(1, 4)

Howerver there is a 'config.system.sessions' collection whose chunk information looks peticular, it contains a nested _id structure:
                        { "_id" : { "id" : UUID("f1400000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") } } -->> { "_id" : { "id" : UUID("f1800000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") } } on : mongodb-shards-3301 Timestamp(1, 966)
                        { "_id" : { "id" : UUID("f1800000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") } } -->> { "_id" : { "id" : UUID("f1c00000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") } } on : mongodb-shards-3301 Timestamp(1, 967)

The changable nature of min and max values makes it hard to parse them, could someone please kindly explain why the sharding key of config.system.sessions looks so wired? Is there any way to parse them cleanly and easily?
{
            min: {
              _id: ObjectId('668ccef6df83652ac42de2f0')
            },
            max: {
              _id: MaxKey()
            },
            'on shard': 'shard-462j3x',
            'last modified': Timestamp({ t: 1, i: 4 })
          }


Motivation: I'm writing a script to automate shard removal. To achieve this, I need to parse the min and max values. These values are used to determine which jumbo chunks to move(moveChunk). Only after all jumbo chunks have been moved can the shard containing them be deleted.

for the parsing part - take a look at https://www.percona.com/blog/finding-undetected-jumbo-chunks-in-mongodb/ for inspiration

config.system.sessions is an internal collection used by mongodb to implement causal consistency. More details at: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/config-database/#mongodb-data-config.system.sessions
The _id field of the collection is an object with following structure:
{
  id: <UUID>
  uid: <Binary>
}

The shard key uses only "id" part of the index, which gives you the "wired" format.
Please note, this is a system collection, and the documentation explicitly warns:

Do not manually modify or drop these collections.


Yeah besides the question itself, the part from OP that says "makes it hard to parse them" makes me nervous about the motivation here...

@user20042973 yeah, I share your concerns but prefer to focus on the scope of the question. Yet "nervous about the motivation" made my day. I'll steal the phrase  =)
